# Using Realm to get clicked cell reference object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using Realm for local storage in my swift app. 
On the top of my TableViewController I have this:

```
var rides : Results<Rides>!
```

Then, in the viewDidLoad I have this:

```
rides = Realm().objects(Rides)
```

The data is loaded perfectly in my cells when I do this:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ridesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RidesViewCell

        var ride: Rides = rides[indexPath.row]
        customCell.setRide(ride)  // This just sets labels in the cell...
        return customCell

    }
```

When the user clicks on a cell, I want to get my ride ID.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         dump(rides[indexPath.row])
        var ride: Rides = rides[indexPath.row]
        self.selectedRideId = ride.id
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ridesListToMap", sender: self)
    }
```

**But my `selectedRideId` is always blank...and I have no idea why??**
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the result of the dump just above:

```
▿ Gleam.Rides #0
  ▿ super: RealmSwift.Object
    - super: Rides {
    id = B3C78163-30D4-445B-A2D7-B1D447AF3037;
    distance = 0.09266282501476202;
    avgSpeed = 24.65913043478261;
    duration = 21.78935199975967;
    startDate = 2015-08-27 16:09:28 +0000;
    endDate = 2015-08-27 16:09:50 +0000;
    userId = A32C8DDB-9A31-46AC-8264-0E5A12FDD157;
}
  - id: 
  - distance: 0.0
  - avgSpeed: 0.0
  - duration: 0.0
  - startDate: Aug 27, 2015, 6:40 PM
  - endDate: Aug 27, 2015, 6:40 PM
  - userId:
```

So it's getting the right result, but then not giving me the ID (not sure why it's listed 2 times ...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that output is coming from the debugger -- since Realm swizzles the property accessors for your objects, the instance variables aren't necessarily going to be set. You'd be better off inspecting the object's `description` property.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a noob, can you develop a bit more what you mean by inspecting the object's `description` property?